Testing, if a file exists. (The point is the point.)
  Look at: %here is the problem

With the point in .\jobname1.tex it does not work, without it, it does.
\TeX
        
        \jobname.tex\vskip\baselineskip
        Testing, if file \jobname1.tex exists
        \vskip\baselineskip
        %here is the problem
        \openin15=.\jobname1.tex   % or \openin15=./filename for current directory only
        %\openin15=\jobname1.tex   % or \openin15=./filename for current directory only
      %here is the problem
        \ifeof15  ... file does {\bf not} exist \else\closein15 ... file exists \fi
        \newwrite\test
        \immediate\openout\test=\jobname1.tex
        \immediate\write\test{\jobname1.tex : This file exists.}
        \immediate\closeout\test
        \vskip\baselineskip
        \input \jobname1.tex
        \bye


what is the name of the file you are trying to read in? you can't use filenames which start with dots.

@cfr See my own answer

you hadn't written one when you posted that comment ;).

@cfr Oh, oh, the cliffs of the basics.. :-(

See \IfFileExists and \@currdir in latex2e.pdf.

Your initial input line tries to input .\jobname.tex which refers to the file .\jobname.tex in your working directory e.g. if your file is called file.tex, you try to input .file.tex.
To specify the current working directory, you need ./.
\TeX

\jobname.tex\vskip\baselineskip
Testing, if file \jobname1.tex exists
\vskip\baselineskip
%here is the problem
\openin15=./\jobname1.tex   % or \openin15=./filename for current directory only
%\openin15=\jobname1.tex   % or \openin15=./filename for current directory only
%here is the problem
\ifeof15  ... file does {\bf not} exist \else\closein15 ... file exists \fi
\newwrite\test
\immediate\openout\test=\jobname1.tex
\immediate\write\test{\jobname1.tex : This file exists.}
\immediate\closeout\test
\vskip\baselineskip
\input \jobname1.tex
\bye

If you really intended to use a filename starting with a dot, you are out of luck. TeX will not write to such a file but will instead return an error. This restriction is implemented for security reasons. You can disable it, I believe, but I would not recommend doing so.

I have mistaken the hint: \openin15=./\jobname1.tex     ./ for directory !!!
 \TeX
    
            \jobname.tex\vskip\baselineskip
            Testing, if file \jobname1.tex exists
            \vskip\baselineskip
            %here is the problem
            \openin15=./\jobname1.tex   % or \openin15=./filename for current directory only
            %\openin15=\jobname1.tex   % or \openin15=./filename for current directory only
          %here is the problem
            \ifeof15  ... file does {\bf not} exist \else\closein15 ... file exists \fi
            \newwrite\test
            \immediate\openout\test=\jobname1.tex
            \immediate\write\test{\jobname1.tex : This file exists.}
            \immediate\closeout\test
            \vskip\baselineskip
            \input \jobname1.tex
            \bye

